# jQuery datepicker weekNumber doesn't match the iso8601Week when firstDay is Sunday

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using the jquery-ui date-picker.
I need to show the week number in the calendar.
Besides - I need to show the week number of the selected week, I use the date-picker method iso8601Week to calculate the selected date and display the week.
This works fine when the first day of week is Monday.
When the first day of week is Sunday the week number at the calendar doesn't match the calculated week number, even though they both use the same iso8601 standard.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({firstDay: 0, showWeek: true, onSelect: function(date){
    date = new Date(date);
    var weekNumber = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(date);
    $("#weekNumber").html($.datepicker.iso8601Week(date));
}});
```

For example: 
When the selected date is 04/16/2015,
The week number in the calendar is **15**,
And the week number in the label is **16**

I think it might have to do with [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8420).

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
My date-picker needs to support any day of week.

See the attached code.
http://jsfiddle.net/08u0pgd5/

Comment: You can use a custom `calculateWeek`; I believe that's what the bug ticket suggests, anyway. Could you clarify what you need? There isn't a clear problem statement in the question

Comment: I need to display the week number of the selected week, and it's obvious that the displayed  week number should be the same as the calendar week number.